# Difficulty with Java Dice Game Assignment

Tags: java

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java so I don't much. I'm learning Java in my uni course and I'm working on a dice game for an assignment.

These are the instructions for the assignment:

> "Write a program that simulates a game of dice. In this game, players take alternate turns rolling two dice. On each turn, they record the sum of the two dice and add this to their total. If a player rolls a doublet (both dice have the same value), then the player gets to roll again. The first player to reach a total of 75 will win.
>
> For games to 20, the output should be as follow (note: no user input is required):
>
> ```
> Player 1 rolls a 3 and a 3
> Player 1 now has 6 Player 1 gets to roll again Player 1 rolls a 5 and a 1
> Player 1 now has 12
> Player 2 rolls a 5 and a 1
> Player 2 now has 6
> Player 1 rolls a 5 and a 6
> Player 1 now has 23
> Player 1 wins with a total of 23"
> ```

My problem is I can't figure out how to switch to the next player's turn without user input and I also can't figure out how to keep track of the player's total sum properly because it resets and it won't reach 75. Please help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        int dice1;
        int dice2;
        int sum;
        boolean endTurn = false;
        boolean endGame = false;
        int totalsum1 = 0;
        int totalsum2 = 0;

        //PLAYER 1

        do
            {

            dice1 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dice2 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sum = dice1 + dice2;
            totalsum1 += sum;

            System.out.println("Player 1 rolls a " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2);
            System.out.println("Player 1 now has " + sum);

            if (dice1 != dice2)
            {

                //endTurn = true;
                while (totalsum1 < 75) ;

            } else
                {

                System.out.println("Player 1 gets to roll again");

                dice1 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
                dice2 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;

                System.out.println("Player 1 rolls a " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2);
                System.out.println("Player 1 now has " + (totalsum1 + dice1 + dice2));

                }

            if (totalsum1 >= 75 && !(totalsum2 >= 75))
            {
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins with a total of " + totalsum1);
                //endGame = true;
                break;

            }

            //PLAYER

            dice1 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dice2 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
            sum = dice1 + dice2;
            totalsum2 += sum;

            System.out.println("Player 2 rolls a " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2);
            System.out.println("Player 2 now has " + sum);

            if (dice1 != dice2)
            {

                endTurn = true;
                while (totalsum2 < 75) ;

            } else
                {

                        System.out.println("Player 2 gets to roll again");

                        dice1 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
                        dice2 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;

                        System.out.println("Player 2 rolls a " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2);
                        System.out.println("Player 2 now has " + (totalsum2 + dice1 + dice2));

                }

                    if (totalsum2 >= 75 && !(totalsum1 >= 75))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player 2 wins with a total of " + totalsum2);
                        endGame = true;
                        break;

                    }
                } while (totalsum1 < 75 && totalsum2 < 75);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. The code needs a complete restructuring, so it's a bit out of scope for the site. Consider this: either it's player one's turn or it's player's two. So you could keep track of that with a boolean (true = player1, false = player2, for example). Based on that you can decide whose turn it is (for strings and for variables like `totalsum1` and `totalsum2`).

Comment: Expanding on Federico's comment I'd suggest you put the code for a player into a separate class that could be named `Player`. Then you just create 2 instances of `Player` and give them a different name, e.g. `Player player1 = new Player("Player 1"); Player player2 = new Player("Player 2");`. Then it's basically just something like : `if( currentPlayer == player1) { currentPlayer = player2; } else { currentPlayer = player1; }` at the start of the loop and then executing the current player's turn and checking whether he has won at the end of the turn.

Comment: `while (totalsum1 < 75) ;` will loop infinitely.

Comment: Also note that things like `while (totalsum1 < 75) ;` are dangerous and will break your application. Assume that `totalsum1` is smaller than 75 - then the loop will execute the empty body indefinitely because `totalsum1` will never change and thus will always be smaller than 75.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. If it's a homework question that your teacher might find and you're afraid of that, then you should have thought about it before asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment and use your already existing code to help you started with the `Player` class:

```
class Player {
  private static final Random generator = new Random();

  private static final int WIN_SCORE = 75;

  private final String name;
  private int totalSum;
  private final int winScore;

  public Player( String name, int winScore ) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.winScore = winScore;
  }

  public boolean executeTurn() {

    boolean rollAgain = roll();

    while( rollAgain ) {
      System.out.println( name + " gets to roll again" );
      rollAgain = roll();
    }

    //returns true if the player won
    return totalSum >= winScore;
  }

  private boolean roll() {
    int dice1 = generator.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
    int dice2 = generator.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
    totalSum += dice1 + dice2;

    System.out.println( name + " rolls a " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2 );
    System.out.println( name + " now has " + totalSum );

    //return true if he may roll again
    return dice1 == dice2;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I've made a few changes, the most notable would be the methods `roll()` and `executeTurn()`. They use your already existing code but are split up a little to simplify rerolling. `roll()` will return `true` if the player is allowed to roll again and `executeTurn()` will let the player roll until there are no more doubles ( you might have to check for the win condition in between but I left that at the end of the turn for now).

`executeTurn()` will now return `true` is the player won so all you'd have to do is loop and alternate the players until one has won.

Example:

```
int winScore = 75;
Player p1 = new Player("Player 1", winScore );
Player p2 = new Player("Player 2", winScore );
Player current = null;

//might be dangerous if due to a bug no player would ever win but we'll leave it simple for now
//we just loop forever and break the loop from the inside whenever a player won
while ( true ) {
  //p1 has had his turn so now it's p2's turn
  if( current == p1 ) {
    current = p2;
  } else {
    current = p1;
  }

  boolean won = current.executeTurn();

  //the player won so end the loop
  if( won ) {
    break;
  }
}

//since we didn't change the current player after he's won we just can get his name
System.out.println(current.getName() + " won");
```

As you can see this starts with player 1 and then just alternates between the two. They take their turns until one has won and then we end the loop and proclaim the winner.

This could be expanded to more than 2 players and by using the scanner to change the `winScore` you pass to the player, but I'll leave that for you as an exercise. :)